# How do I configure the fields to allow empty strings in my MVC 3 app?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3

I first designed my database, then used the EF designer to create a model for use in my MVC app. Most of the nvarchar colums in my database have empty strings as defaults, and they do not allow nulls.

How do I configure the fields to allow empty strings in my MVC 3 app?

```
<div class="editor-label">
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone2)
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone2)
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone2)
</div>
```

The property “Phone2” can be empty, but the default behavior of EF/MVC seems to be to make the field required.

I’ve created a partial class to extend the classes generated by EF, and I also have a MetadataType class to add additional DataAnnotation attributes to the model.

```
[MetadataType(typeof(MyClassMetadata))]
public partial class MyClass
{
    // Adding more properties and methods here, mostly to support use of enums in EF.
}

public class MyClassMetadata
{
    // Empty strings are ok here!
    public string Phone2 { get; set; }

    [AllowHtml]
    [UIHint("Html")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

How do I make a field “not required”? I know I could just skip the validation in my view (use plain controls), but it just seems more “correct” to add the desired behavior to my model instead.

Answer (score 0):

Empty string is allowed by default so you don't need to add any attribute. Moreover:

> I could just skip the validation in my
>   view (use plain controls), but it just
>   seems more “correct” to add the
>   desired behavior to my model instead.

That is actually incorrect assumption. It is used in the simplest applications but generally it is considered as a bad practice. ViewModel is responsible for defining validation of user inputs. You can have different validation for edit and insert - how would you achieve that by data annotations on single class?

Comment: I see your point. But why is my validation kicking in a complaining about the empty field?

Comment: Same problem here ... grrr, you found any solution ?